# Why does the oxygen in NaOH (sodium hydroxide) acquire an electron from the sodium if it's going to become unstable and give away the electron?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrons, ions, protons, oxygen

Mind you that the oxygen is already stable, having an even number of electrons and protons? Is the oxygen really neutral when it has an even number of electrons and protons?

Comment: Sodium hydroxide and any other compounds have a net charge of zero. The whole compound is neutral.

Comment: Sodium hydroxide and hydroxide ions in water solutions are very stable. They do not have tendency to decompose. OTOH, hydroxide ions are very reactive, meeting Broensted-Lawry acids.

Comment: You seem to assume a lot of things which are not there or not things at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome Phillip, to ChemistrySE :D.

I have noticed that you don't seem to have a solid ground on chemistry. It seems like you're struggling to understand how ions can be stable when they have an excess electric charge, compared to neutral atoms.

The reason for this is that you are equating the total charge of the atom with the electron-electron repulsion inside. You think that, because, say, $\mathrm{Cl^{-}}$ has an extra electron, compared to a neutral chlorine atom, it should be more unstable.

In order for an ion to be more unstable than a neutral atom, the inter-electronic repulsion between its electrons should go up *more* than the attraction between the extra electron and the nucleus. At first that idea seems to check out, after all, isn't the new electron facing the repulsion of $N$ electrons, but being attracted by a single nucleus?

This is a sensible way of thinking, if you are considering electron as small fragments of matter sitting till around an atom. But electrons are not classical particles of matter, they are not point like. Rather, electrons behave sort of like a fuzzy cloud. A very strange fuzzy cloud.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with quantum chemistry and the modern atomic model, but since you had difficulties with the basics, I'll refrain from using technical jargon and I'll simply focus on the concepts. If you feel like you're being patronized and would like a more accurate picture, just a leave a comment and I'll edit the answer to fit your tastes.

And because electrons are fuzzy clouds, ant not point particles, they repel each other using rules for fuzzy clouds, not point particles. And it turns out that there is a way for you to arrange fuzzy clouds around an atomic nucleus such that they do not repel each other much. We say that these clouds are *orthogonal* to one another.

As you go along adding electrons around an atom they take shapes that are, preferably, orthogonal to one another, so as to minimize their repulsion, such that each consecutive electron added to a shell increases little of the repulsion each electron in the shell feels, but it greatly increases the electron-nucleus attraction energy, because now there is a new electron being attracted by the nucleus with much the same intensity as the other electrons in the shell.

This can't go on forever, however, for electrons are quantum objects and, as such they have discreet states they can occupy. This means that rather than being an infinitely fluffy and flexible cloud that can deform however it needs, the electron *must* occupy one of a particular selection of distinct shapes that are mutually orthogonal. Thus, eventually, the electrons will run out of shapes on which to contort themselves and the next one will *have* to step on some toes. When that happens, you say that the electrons have closed a *shell* and any additional electron would rise the inter-electronic repulsion energy immensely.

Because electrons can't have any energy they want (this is a consequence of quantum mechanics), there are specific shells they can occupy, at specific distances from the nucleus. Each representing a particular energy level.

In order to add a new electron to an atom that has a filled shell, it has to enter an outer shell. This outer shell electron won't experience repulsion from neighbors in its shell, but it will feel an attenuated nuclear charge, as though it is being attracted by a weaker nucleus. This happens because it's feeling some repulsion from lower shells. The lower shells are *shielding* the outer ones from the nuclear charge.

Outer shells are larger and, as such, they allow the electrons to take more shapes than the smaller, tighter ones, so more electrons can fit inside them.  however, they are also further away from the nucleus, so adding more electrons doesn't usually contribute a great deal for the electrostatic stability of the atom.

Armed with this knowledge, let's take a trip through the periodic table to see how electrons are arranged on the various shells of the atoms.

We start with hydrogen ($\mathrm{H}$), one proton in its nucleus, atomic number 1 (atomic number is often detoned by $Z$). The neutral hydrogen atom has one electron. This electron enter the first shell, where one can fit up to two electrons. This is the only electron the hydrogen has, and it's positioned really, really close to the nucleus so it's very tight to take out. Hence, hydrogen don't often spontaneously loses its electron in orde to become a naked proton. However, one can fit another electron on the hydrogen first shell. Putting a new electron here would likely increase the electron-nucleus attraction energy of the entire system while increasing the electron-electron repulsion a tad less. Which is why you don't often see $\mathrm{H^+}$ as a stand-alone species (the $\mathrm{H^+}$ in acids and bases is short-hand for $\mathrm{H_3 O^+}$ so it doesn't count) but you do see $\mathrm{H^-}$, which is the hydride ion.

Alternatively, the hydrogen could *share* an electron with another atom that could also take a new electron on its shell in order to increase the electron-nucleus attraction energy. We'll see where these atoms are in a moment, but one obvious choice is... another hydrogen atom!

By sharing each of their electrons, two hydrogen atoms can fully occupy their outer shells for maximum electron-nucleus attraction while minimizing electron-electron repulsion *provided* the two atoms stay at such a distance from one another that their electrons don't overlap with one another and their nuclei don't start to repel one another. This effect can be counter-measured by the attraction between the nucleus on a hydrogen and the electrons *around the other*.

When you put it all together, there is a very particular distance between the two hydrogen atoms that optimizes all of these competing influences. Hence we have a molecule of $\mathrm{H_2}$ which is much more stable than isolated gas-phase hydrogen atoms and which has a specific $\mathrm{H-H}$ bond distance and strength.

Now, after hydrogen we have helium ($\mathrm{He}$), $Z=2$. Neutral helium needs two electrons in order to neutralize its nuclear charge. You put one electron in it, and it goes into the first shell, this first shell looks a lot like the one from hydrogen, only it is tighter because the nuclear charge is larger. Then the second electron goes also in the first shell and that's it.

Unlike hydrogen, helium doesn't want any more electrons. Any newer electron would have to occupy an outer shell, increasing the energy of the atom while providing very little electron-nucleus attraction since it would be shielded from the feeble helium nuclear charge by the inner first shell. One such electron would be very weakly bounded to the nucleus, and thus would very easily slip away, which is why we don't often see $\mathrm{He^-}$. For the same reason, helium isn't interested in sharing electrons either.

Alternatively, helium doesn't want to lose any electron either. Losing electrons only decrease electron-electron repulsion energy with *lower shells*, of which helium doesn't have any. In fact, helium is tighter than hydrogen, it's smaller, for it attracts its electrons with greater force than hydrogen. So losing electrons means losing a great amount of electron-nucleus attraction energy, the main stabilizer of the atoms.

Because of this lack of ways to increase its energy by interacting with the electrons of other atoms, helium atoms are chemically inert and all they form are monoatomic gases that do nothing all day long.

The next element is lithium ($\mathrm{Li}$), $Z=3$. Battery superstar and the only metal to have been formed from the primordial nucleosynthesis. Lithium needs three electrons. We've seen this movie before. Two of the electrons go into the first shell but now, unlike helium, there is one extra electron that is required to form a neutral lithium atom. Now, if there is only a lithium atom and the electron is passing by, there will be *some* electrostatic attraction between the positive charge in a semi-filled lithium atom and that electron, but if I explained things correctly, you're likely to anticipate that this outer electron isn't interacting as tightly with the lithium nucleus as the other two electrons. Not only is it further from the nucleus (because it is in an outer shell), it's also being shielded, by the inner shell, from the nuclear charge of the lithium nucleus to which it is bound.

At this point there is *some* repulsion between electrons, because electrons in different shells repel each other more strongly than those in the same shell. I should probably also mention that the extent to which a shell can shield the outer ones from the nuclear charge (as well as the inter-shell repulsion energies) are dependent upon the size of the neighboring shells and their spacing, two parameters that vary from atom to atom and which change for the same atom, with extra electrons or lacking electrons. So all of this we're talking about is an approximation, a tool to help you understand.

If the distance between the inner and outer shells is small enough and lithium nucleus is weak enough, this electron might be extraordinarily loose. Which, it is. Losing that electron would cause all of the inter-electronic repulsion between the two layers to go away, stabilizing the positive-charged lithium *ion* $\mathrm{Li^+}$. One would still have to pluck the electron away, however, because as high as the inter-electronic repulsion is in this case, it's still smaller than the electron-nucleus attraction. Which is why you can still see neutral lithium atoms in the form of the lithium metal and thin gases. If the repulsion between the shells was higher than the electron-nucleus attraction, it would have been impossible to have these gases and metallic pieces to exist in the mild conditions of a laboratory that can be inhabited by humans.

Now, not to extend myself further than I already have, let's talk about your particular problem. Here we have a poly-atomic anion ($\mathrm{OH^-}$) as well as a monoatomic sodium cation $\mathrm{Na^+}$. Sodium is from the family of lithium, only one period down so it has an extra layer between the inner and the outer ones. Much like lithium, sodium would love to lose its electron because then it would get rid of a whole bunch of electron-electron repulsion, so anything capable of taking that electron away from it could easily do it.

The problem is to understand $\mathrm{OH^-}$. Here we have an oxygen bound to a hydrogen and this somehow isn't unstable. Why doesn't this molecule give one electron back to the sodium?

Well... oxygen is on the same period as lithium, the second period of the periodic table. It's an exceedingly small atom because it only has two shells but they are wrapped tighter around its nucleus than the one on lithium, its a *smaller* atom. Though it has an electron-electron repulsion between its inner and outer shell, like lithium, it also has a lot of electron-electron attraction because it has two electrons in its inner shell (which is much like helium) and six electrons on its outer shell.  All of the electrons in the outer shell have a small repulsion to one another but they are attracted by a nucleus which is more charged than lithium. The shielding is not large enough to mask the intense electromagnetic attraction between these electrons and the oxygen atom.

When two atoms share electrons to fill each other's outer shell (we call that *forming a bond*), each of them participate with one of the electrons. A simple bond takes two electrons to form (one from each participant, in covalent bonds.), a double bond takes four and a triple takes six (and so on...).

In water $\mathrm{H_2 O}$, an oxygen is bound to two hydrogen bonds. Oxygen has space for two electrons in its outer shell, more than that and electron repulsion kicks and can't be balanced by the electron-nucleus attraction. hydrogen, as we have seen, has space for one. So, each hydrogen atom forms a bond with an oxygen and everyone is happy.

Except... Oxygen is *six times* more attractive than hydrogen and it is *tight*, small and with a lot of nuclear charge. Even at a distance, oxygen exerts an attractive force on hydrogen's electron that is larger than the attraction that hydrogen exerts over oxygen's electrons. This creates an imbalance. The cloud of electrons, considered collectively, is nudged towards oxygen (but you said electrons had definite shapes! Well they do, but the shapes are defined by the potential they are experiencing. Electrons under the influence of *two* nuclei instead of one have different shapes, one of which is this nudged one).

When one of the $\mathrm{H-O}$ of water is split, it is far more likely that the electron *pair* that forms the bond stays with the oxygen. One of those electrons was originally with the oxygen anyway, but the other one was originally in the hydrogen, so it adds an extra negative charge to the remaining $\mathrm{OH}$ bundel of atoms, and you have the following
$$
\mathrm{B\ +\ H_2 O\ \to\ BH⁺\ +\ OH^-}
$$
where $B$ is something that has extra pairs of electrons on its outer layers, such as a nitrogen atom bonded to two other hydrogen atoms. Nitrogen needs three more electrons to fill its outer shell, which it can easily get from forming bonds with eager hydrogens, but it does have a single pair o electrons that originally belonged to itself, so it can go this:
$$
\mathrm{N H_3(aq)\ +\ H_2 O(l)\ \to\ N H_4^+(aq)\ +\ OH^-(aq)}
$$
indeed, oxygen itself can provide electron pairs like this:
$$
\mathrm{H_2 O(l)\ +\ H_2 O(l)\ \to\  H_3 O^+(aq)\ +\ OH^-(aq)}
$$
a famous reaction called water autoprotolysis, often written like this, for stoichiometric friendliness:
$$
\mathrm{2 H_2 O(l)\ \to\  H_3 O^+(aq)\ +\ OH^-(aq)}
$$

The existence of species with available electron pairs to share with electron-depleted species (such as a hydrogen in a water molecule) is what drives the creation of negatively charged things. An amine ($\mathrm{N H_3}$) comes long and passes close to a water molecule minding its business. One of the hydrogens notice all of those loose and cushy electrons, nothing like the tight and depleted cloud that oxygen is offering it, and decides to change partners. The remaining hydroxyl ($\mathrm{OH^-}$) has a more evenly distributed electron cloud but still has atoms with all their shells filled.

The weakness of the hydrogen-oxygen bond is a result of the small size and high charge of the oxygen atom and the disproportional attraction that it has for hydrogen's shared electrons (this is a didactic statement, in reality electrons in a molecule aren't distinguishable, but speaking about that would open a can of worms that is better addressed in a different question).

When the $\mathrm{H=O}$ bond breaks, the oxygen is left with a negative charge *but a filled outer shell*, since the two electrons stais with it. That is what stabilizes the charged hydroxyl. In order to transfer the proton and lower the overall charge of the species to zero, the oxygen in the hydroxyl ($\mathrm{OH^-}$) would have to rip electrons from its outer shell... something that is likely not going to happen.

Incidentally, hydroxyl can still lose its last electron, provided you mix it with something with even better electrons or other conditions that allow for that bond breakage. The resulting ion is $\mathrm{O^{2-}}$ which forms oxides.

But one thing you can't do is have the hydroxyl exist as a neutral species an then *it* rips the electron away from sodium. That's not what is going on. In order to form a hydroxyl ion, you need to mix something with water that will be able to break that bond. Neutral hydroxyl has half-filled shells (thus making it a *radical*) and it is very much not stable. Hydroxyl ion is formed from things that have hydroxyl groups, the most abundant of which is water.

It's the opposite of sodium, which is a larger atom than oxygen with an appreciable electron-repulsion energy, eager to lose the outer shell.  Sodium, therefore, loses its outer electron in order to ditch the electron-repulsion energy whereas oyxgen retains hydrogen's electron when another species with better electrons come along to snatch its hydrogen away from it.

The two resulting species $\mathrm{Na^+}$ and $\mathrm{OH^-}$ are, therefore, very stable... Provided there are opposite-charged things around them to stabilize them. Although the microscopic sodium cation and hydroxyl molecule are very stable, if you bunch a mole of them together in order to get a macroscopic piece of them, the mutual electrostatic repulsion between each individual ion would make it impossible to counter. But if you mix *the same amount* of opposite charged things such that opposite charges are close together, then you can make a big thing like, say, a lump of table salt ($\mathrm{Na Cl}$) or, in your case, the white, soapy-like sodium hydroxide ($\mathrm{NaOH}$).

Water is a molecule with a dipole moment, which means that it works like a little triangle with one vertex negative and two others positive. When you put something charged into water, it *may* get in between the ions in the substance stuck together by electrostatic forces and its negative tip can form a tiny electrostatic interaction with the cation while its two other positive vertices form electrostatic interactions with the anions.

One molecule of water, individually, for an electrostatic interaction with the ions that is comparatively weaker than the ionic bond that the charged species would formed between themselves, but you surround them with a thick coat of water molecules (a process known as hydration) and then, depending on the properties of the ions and the lattice they were forming before water came in to break it, it might be better for the ions to interact with this combined water coat than with themselves, at which point the substance made from the charged species dissolves.

So you can have $\mathrm{Cl^-(aq)}$ or $\mathrm{N H_4^+(aq)}$ the $\mathrm{(aq)}$ indicating that the species are surrounded by a coat of water molecules, but you can never have $\mathrm{Cl^-(s)}$ or $\mathrm{N H_4^+(l)}$ that is a solid or liquid macroscopic substance made of charged parts of a single type.

We've come a long way. Hopefully by now you have understood why it is that some charge-excess species are more stable than neutral-charged alternative versions of themselves. It's all quantum mechanics' fault!

If the explanation is still murky and strange, I hope that, at least, you come out of this answer with better questions than the ones with which you walked into it. Chemistry is a fascinating subject, but also a deep and convoluted one, full of red herrings and surprising twists. Don't let the difficulty discourage you!